# Expandable Search Form

Tags: html, css

I am working on Expandable Search but facing one problem. When i click on search bar then search bar is expanding. But right side content is moving down. I wanna hide right side content when search bar is expand similar to stackoverflow search bar.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.mainheader {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FAFAFB;
  border-top: 3px solid #F48024;
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 1px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 1px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 1px #ccc;
}

.innerheader {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

.logo_name {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 13px;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #7db9e8 50%,#1e5799 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.ga_a {
  float: left;
}

.ga_b {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.ga_b ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  line-height:1;
}

.ga_b ul>li {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.ga_b ul>li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande",Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif;
}

.ga_b ul>li:hover {
  background-color: #ECECEC;
}

.ga_c {
  float: left;
}

.ga_c input {
  outline: none;
}

.ga_c input[type=search] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.ga_c input::-webkit-search-decoration,
.ga_c input::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  display: none; 
}

.ga_c input[type=search] {
  background: #ededed url(https://static.tumblr.com/ftv85bp/MIXmud4tx/search-icon.png) no-repeat 9px center;
  border: solid 1px #ffffff;
  padding: 9px 10px 9px 32px;
  width: 175px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.ga_c input[type=search]:focus {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
}

.ga_c input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}

.ga_c input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}

.ga_d {
  float: left;
}

.ga_d ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  display: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainheader">
  <div class="innerheader">
    <div class="ga_a">
       <a class="navbar-brand logo_name" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div> 
    <div class="ga_b">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="active-link">Text One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Text Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Text Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
    <div class="ga_c">
      <form>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
      </form>
    </div> 
    <div class="ga_d">
      <ul>
        <li>Login</li>
        <li>Register</li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the *positioning*:

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box} /* recommended */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.mainheader {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1000px; /* added / needs to match the .innerheader width */
  margin: 0 auto; /* added */
  background-color: #FAFAFB;
  border-top: 3px solid #F48024;
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 1px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 1px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 1px #ccc;
}

.innerheader {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto; /* modified */
}

.logo_name {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 13px;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #7db9e8 50%,#1e5799 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.ga_a {
  float: left;
}

.ga_b {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.ga_b ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 7px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.ga_b ul>li {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.ga_b ul>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000; /*black*/
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande",Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif;
}

.ga_b ul>li:hover {
  background: #ECECEC;
}

.ga_c {
  position: relative; /* needs to be set because of the absolute positioned child */
  float: left;
}

.ga_c input {
  outline: none;
}

.ga_c input[type=search] {
  position: absolute; /* needs to be positioned absolutely, i.e. be removed from the normal document flow so that it can "overlay" and other element, of course the z-index needs to be set */
  z-index: 9999; /* usually something big just to be sure it stays on top / in front of everything else */
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.ga_c input::-webkit-search-decoration,
.ga_c input::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  display: none; 
}

.ga_c input[type=search] {
  background: #ededed url(https://static.tumblr.com/ftv85bp/MIXmud4tx/search-icon.png) no-repeat 9px center;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  padding: 9px 10px 9px 32px;
  width: 175px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.ga_c input[type=search]:focus {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
}

.ga_c input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}

.ga_c input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}
.ga_d {
  position: relative; /* positioned relative to its normal position so that we can move it with "directional" properties  */
  left: 229px; /* moved to the right by the width of the .ga_c (inspected the element) */
  float: left;
}

.ga_d ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  display: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainheader">
  <div class="innerheader">
    <div class="ga_a">
       <a class="navbar-brand logo_name" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div> 
    <div class="ga_b">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="active-link">Text One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Text Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Text Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
    <div class="ga_c">
      <form>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
      </form>
    </div> 
    <div class="ga_d">
      <ul>
        <li>Login</li>
        <li>Register</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With your structure, it is not possible using css only. However if change the structure you could have something like this.

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: arial;
}

input{
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: .3s;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 250px;
}

input:focus{
  width: 400px;
}

input:focus + div{
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li{
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

div {
 display: inline-block;
 transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<input type="search" placeholder="Search">
<div class="ga_d">
 <ul>
  <li>Login</li>
  <li>Register</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```